# Xelatex and bib latex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xetex

Xelatex does not seem to make hyphenation in German bibliography even though the entries are explicitly announced as German. xelatex + biber + xelatex + xelatex. Pdflatex does not have their problem. How can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{xunicode}
  \usepackage{xltxtra}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
  \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
  \newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}[Script=Cyrillic]{CMU Serif}
  \newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Script=Greek]{CMU Serif}
  \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
  \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
  \setotherlanguages{german,french,greek,latin,spanish,italian,english}
  \setkeys{greek}{variant=ancient}
  \setkeys{german}{spelling=new}
  \enablehyphenation
  
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=gost-footnote,bibstyle=gost-footnote,language=auto,autolang=other,autocite=footnote,citetracker=true,ibidtracker=false,opcittracker=false,citereset=chapter,citepages=omit,sorting=nty,notetype=foot+end]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\usepackage{filecontents,hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Incollection{Reimitz:2004b,
author = {Helmut Reimitz},
title = {Der Weg zum Königtum in historiographischen Kompendien der Karolingerzeit},
booktitle = {Der Dynastiewechsel von 751. Vorgeschichte, Legitimationsstrategien und Erinnerung},
editor = {Matthias Becher and Jörg Jarnut},
address = {Münster},
publisher = {Scriptorium},
year = {2004},
pages = {283-326},
language = {german},
hyphenation = {german},
shorttitle = {Der Weg zum Königtum},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\large

Test.\autocites{Reimitz:2004b} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: how old is your tex system?

Comment: April 2020, MacTex.

Comment: try with `langid = {german}`

Comment: All worked, that you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to change the 'hyphenation' field name to 'langid' from within the tex file rather than changing all entries in a bib file?

Comment: you can setup a source map.

Comment: `hyphenation` is a legacy alias for `langid` and is automatically remapped by Biber. If I run your example without change I get `\field{langid}{german}` in the `.bbl` file and I get hyphenation. It should not matter at all whether you use `hyphenation = {german},` or `langid = {german}`. (Probably not relevant to the question, but I can't see a matching `\fi` for the `\ifxetex`. I'm also not sure if it is officially supported to set `polyglossia` language options with `\setkeys`)

Comment: 1. Strangely, with `hyphenation` field I could not get a very long German word hyphenated, but `langid` solved it. Why, I have no idea, I am just reporting the result. 2. There was a \fi, it fell off.

Answer (score 1):

The posted MWE hyphenates words correctly for me

[image: Karo-lingerzeit]

[image: Kompendi-en]

While the `hyphenation` field is deprecated now in favour of the `langid` field, it continues to work and is remapped by Biber to `langid`. Indeed when I run the MWE, the `.bbl` file contains

```
\field{langid}{german}
```

It is not inconceivable that some code would stop this field aliasing from happening, but that sort of code is not present in your MWE.

---

Check that your `.bbl` file contains `\field{langid}{german}`. Then check if XeLaTeX can hyphenate any German words (if properly marked up) [i.e. check if German hyphenation works outside of a `biblatex` context].

---

Note that the MWE is missing the matching `\fi` for the `\ifxetex` in line four.